# $_POST is not returning anything

Tags: php, html, apache

I am new in using PHP - i am trying to get the data from data sent to the Apache server using $_POST - but i am getting nothing 
below is the details

i am using XAMPP on Windows 7 for setup (Apache & PHP)

and I am having two files 
welcome.html which is calling welcome.php to echo the contents got from the html

Note that I have nothing reported in Apache error log file 
C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log

any idea what went wrong here

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

and 
welcome.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>

<head>
     <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>

<body>
     Welcome 
         <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
</body>
```

Comment: i think it is working fine, did you get any error?

Comment: Did you enter a name into the field?

Comment: What does `print_r($_SERVER);`, `print_r($_POST);` and `print_r($_REQUEST);` output?

Comment: Could you show the output of `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: There's nothing wrong here, just copied and paste all your code without changing anything and works

Comment: The only time it does not print anything is when u don't enter name

Comment: I was expecting getting the values entered by me in the html page 
for Example :Welcome myName   & You email address is : myemal@gmail.com      -- or I am missing something here ?

Comment: How can you know the email, think about it...

Answer (score 0):

for testing your php file. direct run this welcome.php from your localhost
like this http://localhost/welcome.php

```
<?php
echo 'Check your name';
?>
```

if you see "Check your name"; then your local server is working . else need to run local server

this is your html welcome.html file

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

then submit your form using name text

then check your code using

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
print_r($_POST);
?>

 <head>
 <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
 </head>
```

Welcome

everything work here

Comment: Thanks all for help